# Join in Django?

Tags: sql, django, join, orm

I'm trying to make an application in Django, but I need to do a JOIN in Django, Somethin like that:

```
SELECT User.name, Post.contain from User, Post where Post.User_id = User.id;
```

Hoy can i get the User.name?

My model is

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    contenido = models.TextField(max_length = 140)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True, blank = True)
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

really thank you for the help =)

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time, you should not worry about joins. This is ORMs job.

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user)
```

After the first query, the user should be in the ORM cache, so don't worry about performance unless you detect a performance bottleneck (premature optimization is the root of all evil).

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if forloop.first %}<h1>{{ post.user.name }}{% endif %}
    <li>{{ post.contain }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

If you really want to be a control freak:

```
posts = Post.objects.select_related().filter(user=user_id)\
                                     .values('user__name', 'contain')
```

[update]

`django.contrib.auth.models.User` lacks a field called `name`. It has `username`, `first_name` and  `last_name`. There is also the `get_full_name`method`suggested by karthikr.

What is the result of the following?

```
Post.objects.filter(user=user_id)
```

The template should be:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
    <h1>{% trans 'Posts for' %}
        {{ post.usuario.get_full_name|default:post.usuario.username }}
    </h1>
    <ul>
    {% endif %}
      <li>{{ post.contenido }}</li>
    {% if forloop.last %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Try the same queryset without the filter to see if the problem is with the filter (like the user having no posts).

```
Post.objects.select_related().filter(usuario=user_id)\
                         .values('usuario__username', 'contenido')
```

Comment: {{post.user.name}} should be {{post.user.get_full_name}}

Comment: @karthikr: the OP snippet has `User.name`, I can't assume `User` is the same object from `django.contrib.auth.models.User`.

Comment: @Cris_Towi: can't replicate your problem without seeing your model definition. please update your question with more information.

Comment: @Cris_Towi: I want to help you, but it works for me. Is there any error message? My answer was updated, have you tried some of the suggestions? If so, do you mind posting your results?